# How to backport a single file from "today" to "very long ago"?

Tags: git, rebase

Consider the following scenario:

- a `topic` branch started with commit A
- at commit B on `topic` branch, a utility script file was created
- since commit B, that file has been revised by multiple commits to `topic`
- I decided that its final form developed in `topic` will be useful for the `master` branch
- when rebasing `topic` on `master`, I want to avoid multiple conflicts involving all the edits to this file that happened between commit B and `topic`'s head; I want to express the following intention: "**Hey git, whenever you see a conflict involving this file during rebasing `topic` onto `master`, automatically resolve it by using the version from `master`**"

How do I?

Comment: Read about strategies called `ours` and `theirs` and choose the appropriate one in your case.

Comment: `ours` and `theirs` are THE most broken concepts in git. They are moving targets. It is not humanly possible to memorize which is which in which situation (merge vs rebase vs several options that can affect the meaning of `ours` and `theirs`). I refuse to acknowledge the existence of this utterly broken feature. It is like "credit" and "debet" in accounting: notions that originally made sense but then the entirety of accounting developed away from that sense.

Comment: Not many complains. If you think so, just fix and send patch upstream, that's how open source works.